# Android arcgis how to use only a layer from a service containing 3 layers?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-android

I have this service:

http://*************/ArcGIS/rest/services/mod_streets/MapServer

Layers:

```
Numbers (0)
StreetsGraph (1)
Streets (2)
```

And I'm trying to use only Numbers **(note /0)**

```
    map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer layerStreets = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://*************/ArcGIS/rest/services/mod_streets/MapServer/0");
    map.addLayer(layerStreets);
```

This is not working.

But this works (removing /0 but all layers are displayed into the map)

```
    map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer layerStreets = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://*************/ArcGIS/rest/services/mod_streets/MapServer");
    map.addLayer(layerStreets);
```

**I want to see only Numbers in my Android map...Any ideas?**

Comment: Did my code work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can not use ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer for this issue. You should use ArcGISFeatureLayer instead. 
Sample code below.

```
String URL = "http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Specialty/ESRI_StateCityHighway_USA/MapServer/0";
ArcGISFeatureLayer fLayer = new ArcGISFeatureLayer(URL, MODE.ONDEMAND);
map.addLayer(layerStreets);
```